# Knockout + isotope + mbest binding, complex template not displaying properly

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to get isotope sorting working in combination with knockout. I've found an isotope binding for knockout by Michael Best (https://gist.github.com/mbest/7577891), and this works, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/ACSGx/. However, when the template is just a little more complex (like surrounding the text with ...) it breaks and the layout gets messed up. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Libido/cdwjjdpo/2/
The only thing I changed was surround the div data bound to the text property with another div:

```
<div id="container" data-bind="isotope: { data: items, isotopeOptions: getOptions }, click: addItem">
    <div><!-- Remove this and it works -->
        <div data-bind="text: text, click: $parent.removeItem, clickBubble: false"></div>
    </div><!-- Remove this and it works -->
</div>
```

I inspected the code and I think the problem is both the outer and inner div are processed and get the isotope-item classes and styles, but I'm not sure.
Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Well this has to be the fastest answer to my own question.. All I had to do was pass an itemSelector into isotopeOptions (the default = "*")